# MySQL Update nth character in existing entry

Tags: mysql

How do I update a single character, in table '*units*', column '*status*' (varchar), at a specific position (varies)?

```
UPDATE units SET status = SELECT INSERT(status, 3, 1, '2') WHERE id='1'
```

When running this (in PHP) This give me an error *'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version....'*

Rather than the desired

Before '00000'

After '00200'

There are *lots* of examples of the SELECT INSERT function but all with a predefined string, rather than using an existing entry.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Just remove `SELECT` before `INSERT(...`

Comment: *This give me an error* NEVER alter the error message, always provide its complete text.

Comment: *There are lots of examples of the SELECT INSERT function* No, the function is `INSERT()` only. `SELECT` is query clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `SELECT` before `INSERT(...`

```sql
UPDATE units SET status = INSERT(status, 3, 1, '2') WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated!